# Determine a directory is a package in swift

Tags: swift, package, nsfilemanager

How can I tell if a file is a package rather than a directory?

```
var isDir = ObjCBool(false)
let exists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path, isDirectory: &isDir)

return isDir.boolValue
```

This code returns true for both directories and packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a Cocoa method, `isFilePackageAtPath`, on NSWorkspace for that.

```
import Cocoa

let sw = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()

if sw.isFilePackageAtPath("/Applications/Xcode.app") {
    // True, so this will execute.
}
if sw.isFilePackageAtPath("/usr/bin") {
    // False, so this won't execute.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping find that missing jigsaw piece.